# Touch responsiveness on iPod

Tags: ios, input, touch, unity-game-engine

I wrote a simple code that makes an object follow moursor or touch input and works so fast and responsive on editor but when I deploy it on my iPod, it has a slight delay. If you move your finger fast enough, you can see that the object takes time to reach to your finger, it's slight but noticable.

There is no problem in the path that object has to follow in order to get dragged around the scene, problem is it's always like 10 pixels late to the finger's current position. It's like input is checked on less intervals than update.

So is there anyway to make it more responsive? Like with what we can do with physic that we can force it to call more Fixed Update or anything similar.

I want it to follow my finger on the screen fast, without any delay.

I tried these so far with no fruit:

1) Changing FPS ro 60.
2) Changing various settings in AppController.mm

Thanks.

Comment: Without any indication of how you've implemented this, how can we possibly suggest potential improvements? (i.e.: Show us the (relevant) parts of your code.)

Comment: How old is the iPod? have you got any large number-crunching tasks which might maybe slow it down?

Remember your Mac is probably quite powerful compared to your iPod

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys:

1) Even with the simplest code I have this problem, a new Unity project and one line of code that gets input's touch, translates it into game's position and puts it into the gameobject's transform component.

2) iPod touch is 4G and runs iOS 5.0.1 and is Jailbroken.

Comment: Can I provide any more info to help?

Comment: If the Unity event loop is delayed, OnGUI() is going to be slow to respond to a mouse update.  Try logging the frames per second on both your Mac and ipod (ipad?) and report those values back.

Comment: I'm not using OnGUI, I have this problem with a new clean project and just one line getting input touch, changing it to world space and assigning it to an object's transform's position.

Comment: I tested it on two different Android devices and it ran way better. What can be the problem?